# How can I use the CDN version of CKEditor with an alternative skin hosted on my server?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mime-types

I have read the documentation and countless posts about using alternative skins (as opposed to the standard 'moono' skin) with CKEditor. I am using the CDN version of CKEditor, but I want to use a different skin. So, I have downloaded the skin of choice (bootstrapck) and I am hosting it from my server. Everything works great, until I push it to my production server. In production it is not recognizing the alternative skin I wish to use. Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
    ....
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1"></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            skin : 'bootstrapck,/lib/ckeditor/skins/bootstrapck/'
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This exact same code works perfectly on my local testing server, but it doesn't work at all on my production server. Here is what I see in the console on production:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.example.com/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' 
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, 
and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your production server is serving .js files with incorrect mimetype. If your production server is Apache ensure you have [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)  and the following line in the `httpd.conf`

```
AddType text/javascript .js
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using node.js though. How can I update the mimetype of javascript files served from a node.js server?